# Extract substring using importxml and substring-after

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using Google sheet 'ImportXML', I was able to extract the following data from a url(in cell A2) using:

```
=IMPORTXML(A2,"//a/@href[substring-after(., 'AGX:')]").
```

Data:

```
/vector/AGX:5WH
/vector/AGX:Z74
/vector/AGX:C52
/vector/AGX:A27
/vector/AGX:C6L
```

But, I want to extract the code after "/vector/AGX:". The code is not fixed to 3 letters and number of rows is not fixed as well.

I used `=INDEX(SPLIT(AP2,"/,'vector',':'"),1,2)`. But it applied to only one line of data. Had to copy the index+split function to the whole column and had to insert an additional column to store the codes.

```
5WH
Z74
C52
A27
C6L
```

But, I want to be able to extract the code(s) after AGX: using ImportXML in one go. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Your issue is in how you are implementing the [index](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) formula. The first parameter returns the rows (in your case each element) and the second the column (in your case either `AGX` or the code after that).

If instead of getting a single cell we apply this formula on a range and we do not set any value for the row, the formula will return all the values achieving what you were aiming for. Here is its implementation *(where `F1:F5` will be the range of values you want this formula to be applied)* :

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(F1:F5,"/,'vector',':'"),,2)
```

If you are interested in a solution simply using `IMPORTXML` and `XPATH`, according to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after) you could use a **substring** as follows:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//a/@href[substring-after(.,'SGX:')]")
```

The drawback of this is that it will return the full string and not exclusively what is after the `SGX:` which means that you would need to use a Google sheet formula to splitting this. This is the furthest I have achieved exclusively using XPath. In XML it would be easier to apply a `forEach` and really select what is after the `:` but I believe in sheets is more complicated if not impossible just using XPath.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Thanks for your input! First off, it helped solve my issue. I was wondering, though, if it's possible to extract the same data by using ImportXML, Xpath, substring-after and substring-before instead? I saw it being used elsewhere but I'm not sure how to implement it in my case.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include that specification too. It would be good if you could share the page you are getting the info from in case my second answer is not working so that I could test it to figure out where the issue might be. Also, if the answer worked for you please consider accepting my answer so that other users with the same issue can easily see how to solve it.

Comment: Hi Mateo, I'm getting an empty output with the second solution. I've attached the example link(s) here. I'm trying to scrape stock codes from this link. Here is the code from the 2nd solution. `=IMPORTXML("https://www.investingnote.com/stocks?page=1","substring-before(//a/@href,':')")`. Your earlier solution on the same page works.`=INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTXML("https://www.investingnote.com/stocks?page=1","//a/@href[substring-after(., 'SGX:')]"),"/,'stocks',':'"),,2)`.  The original output should look like this. `=IMPORTXML("https://www.investingnote.com/stocks?page=1","//a/@href")`.

Comment: I have updated my answer. This is as far as I could do just using XPath, I believe you will need to use a formula anyway.

Comment: I appreciate it. Thanks for looking into this. I was hopeful but then again, since I am new to Sheets, I'm not sure what's possible and what's not. At least, I know it's not possible (at least for now). Your earlier solution works well! I will accept the earlier answer and mark it as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm if it's flagged as resolved at your end?

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks a lot ! :D